# Adding icon to text field based on server side validation(Formik+Yup+Material UI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, formik, yup

I am trying to show a tick or cross icon in a text field based on the api response.

My text field looks like this. I've added inputProps to it and added an adornment. But I want to display different icons based on a function which will return if its valid or not.

```
          <TextField
            error={errors.username && touched.username}
            variant="outlined"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="username"
            label="Username"
            onChange={handleChange}
            helperText={touched.username && errors.username}
            InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end" disablePointerEvents="true">
                  <CheckCircleOutlineIcon
                    style={{ color: green[500] }}
                    fontSize="small"
                  ></CheckCircleOutlineIcon>
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
          />
```

But this keeps showing all the time, in the handleChange event i want to trigger a function which lets me decide on which icon i will show. I tried a lot of google search, but it dint help.
I see this can be achieved easily in mdBootstrap like the image i have shown, but i am using material ui and yup for validations and formik.
Please help!
[image]

Comment: u need to store value of icon in state and based on state switch the icon. in your code I only see one icon `<CheckCircleOutlineIcon  />`. Would be good you create example in  codesandbox.com

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue:

My steps to fix it:

1. Made my Formik {Field} Module into the Material UI {Textfield} Module to be able to add the icons using the InputProps={}. This also required readding the {handleChange, handleBlur} props as validation didn't kick in on the fields otherwise.
2. I used endAdorment property to add the icons to the field and added conditions directly inside it to display the correct icon based on the Formik validation.

I haven't checked it with an API call validation, but I assume it works similarly with it.

```js
<Field
            component={TextField}
            error={errors.username && touched.username && true}
            variant="outlined"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="username"
            label="Username"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            helperText={touched.username && errors.username}
            InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end" disablePointerEvents="true">
                  {errors.username && touched.username && (
                    <CancelIcon
                      style={{ color: "red" }}
                      fontSize="default"
                    ></CancelIcon>
                  )}
                  {!errors.username && touched.username && (
                    <CheckCircleIcon
                      style={{ color: "#05cc30" }}
                      fontSize="default"
                    ></CheckCircleIcon>
                  )}                  
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
          />
```

I added conditions directly inside the endAdornment which checks for the `errors.username`  as well as if it was touched and displays Cross or if touched and `!errors.username`  it changes to green tick.